# This volume can not be resized

Tags: disk-utility

I'm trying to create a partition but the Disk Utility says it cannot be resized, and the + button appears greyed out. Why is that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22021834#22021834) Apple support question:

> You cannot dynamically resize an ExFAT partition, like you can an HFS+ partition on a GPT volume.  It's a limitation of the ExFAT file system, I believe.  You'll have to destructively repartition and reformat.

So, you have to reformat the entire drive. Remember THIS WILL DELETE ALL OF THE DATA ON THAT DRIVE, so make sure you move all of your files off before you do this. Let me know if this answer wasn't clear or you want help walking through the steps to do this.

Comment: Mmmm... The thing is I want to use it for Windows, Mac and PS4 and PS4 needs ExFAT + MBR scheme. I assume I can set one of the partitions to ExFAT after the fact?

Comment: Yes, @Óscar but you won't be able to resize it so choose your size wisely

Comment: Thanks for your concern, @NoahL. Yes, I did that so that my drive would work for PS4, Mac and Windows.